# Creating char arrays with << (less less) in C

Tags: c, arrays

What does it mean when arrays are defined like:

```
char a[256<<1];
char b[256<<1];
```

Can anyone see a reason why code would work when a is defined before b and not work when a is defined after b? Like this would not work:

```
char b[256<<1];
char a[256<<1];
...other code with a and b;
```

Comment: Are you sure this is the reason? Because I doubt it. If these two lines are one after the other, changing their order doesn't matter.

Comment: Your problem lies elsewhere. Probably you are walking off the end of *one* of those arrays and clobbering the other when they happen to have the wrong ordering in memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't immediately see a reason because there's no context. Possibly if there is a certain structure that the arrays belong in that is being accessed via pointer arithmetic then yes I can see a reason for this happening or just pointer arithmetic in general that assumes an order of a and b. Otherwise I see no reason as to why this would cause a failure. If you could provide context that would help.

What rearranging this has done is probably show a buffer overflow somewhere in your code (maybe a just overflowed into b before but now because of this new order a overflows into some other stack variables and makes weird things happen). This is quite common if you're using unsafe calls such as gets for lines that are longer than 512 characters or something of the sort.

And FYI << is the left shift operator so it takes 256 and left shifts it by 1 bit which makes it 512.

Comment: Is has something to do with pointers and memory adesses later, but it's outside of the code I can see. I was not sure if << has something to do with it or not. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`256<<1` means 256 shifted left one bit, which is 512. As for why the code works in one order and not in the other, the most likely explanation is that there's a bug in the code, it accesses one array out of bounds, and by luck in one case that access lands in the other array. But there are other possibilities too. For example, the code might compute the difference of a pointer into each array and expect a positive result.

Answer (score 0):

In your case the `<<` operator means bit left shift. So `x<<1` is the integer `x` shifted left by one bit, that is the same as `x*2`, and `256<<1`  is 512.

Answer (score 0):

<< is left shift that mean that you defined array with 256 left shifted by 1 = 256 *2 = 512

Why one code works and the other one not is depending on the use of a and b.

please edit your question with the rest of the code if you want an answer on it.

Answer (score 0):

Both code compile :

https://ideone.com/hHjSW

https://ideone.com/9eLPx

And `256<<1` is equivalent to `512`
It a left binary shift.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that the shift operators are used instead of literal '512' in order to clarify/emphasize how the following code and data work - 'this structure is twice the range of one byte'.

Software that behaves differently when data is moved around usually means that one or more structures are being overrun/overwritten.  These are char arrays and so check the indexing.